# Using 'apply' with arrays inside Pandas dataframe elements

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, apply

I am working with pandas dataframes which contain arrays inside the dataframe elements.  I'm trying to "apply" a function to these elements, and then return an array.  But I have some very inconsistent behavior.  The function runs okay the first few times, but then it fails.  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def g(x):  # Function fails if I omit the .tolist()
    return (np.concatenate([x['B'][1:], x['C'][1:]])).tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : (1,2,3), \
                   'B': (np.array([0,1,2,3]),np.array([3,4,5,6]),np.array([6,7,8,9])), \
                   'C': (np.array([0,1,2,3]),np.array([2,9,6,9]),np.array([2,4,6,7]))})
# Before we start
print(df)
print("B is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'B']))
# First time 
df['G'] = df.apply(g, axis=1)
print("G is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'G']))
# Second time
df['H'] = df.apply(g, axis=1)
print("H is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'H']))
# Third time 
df['I'] = df.apply(g, axis=1)
print("I is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'I']))
# Fourth time - this one fails for me
df['J'] = df.apply(g, axis=1)
print("J is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'J']))
# Fifth time 
df['K'] = df.apply(g, axis=1)
print("K is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'K']))
```

The code runs fine for me, up to the line df['J'], where it fails. The output is like this:

```
   A             B             C
0  1  [0, 1, 2, 3]  [0, 1, 2, 3]
1  2  [3, 4, 5, 6]  [2, 9, 6, 9]
2  3  [6, 7, 8, 9]  [2, 4, 6, 7]
B is type:   <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
G is type:   <class 'list'>
H is type:   <class 'list'>
I is type:   <class 'list'>
```

Then there is a big long error message which finishes with `"ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1"`, and there is also a `"KeyError: 'J'"` in there too.

The crazy thing is that the function runs fine the first few times.  My questions are:

- Why does my code fail when it gets to `df['J']`?
- How can I get `g(x)` to return a numpy array rather than a list? If I leave out the `.tolist()` it gives me an error.
- Is there an easier way to work with arrays inside dataframe elements?

Any help would be **hugely** appreciated! I've spent 2 days trying to understand what is going on here.

P.S. I haven't explained why I am using arrays inside dataframe elements, but I can explain if you think it would help.

Comment: The reason your code fails at `J` is because once you get to 6 columns, pandas fits the result of `g` (which is of length 6) to the existing columns. It then returns a dataframe with 6 columns, which does not fit in column `J`. Try `df.apply(g, axis=1)` right before assigning it to `J`.

Comment: @IanS Thanks for the explanation, I was struggling on that too. How comes pandas only considers it as a dataframe this time and not the previous? It seems that before, it rendered a `Series` but suddenly it becomes a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @ysearka I've been struggling with this too, and I don't have an exact explanation. I guess pandas makes a guess based on the dimension of the result, but I don't know how to force it to do otherwise.

Comment: Also Michael, the reason you need `tolist` is because if `g` returns a numpy array then pandas will forcefully try to map the resulting numpy array of length 6 to the dataframe columns (3 of them intially). With `tolist` you tell pandas to make the result an actual column value. Until you reach 6 columns that is, and then it breaks down.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments guys!  @IanS I think you have hit the nail on the head.  To prove it, I tried adding a seventh column just before the attempt at J.  Then the whole script ran through to completion without an error!  So the problem is when g returns an array with the same number of elements as there are columns in the database.  The problem remains though, how do we deal with this?  Can we find a way to force pandas to treat the result as a list or array or tuple or whatever, to be put into the column?

Comment: @IanS @ysearka - I was just looking at the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.apply` and saw the argument `reduce`.  It says:  _If the DataFrame is empty, apply will use reduce to determine whether the result should be a Series or a DataFrame._  I tried it but it didn't work, I guess because the dataframe I passed was not empty.  But I don't understand how apply can be returning anything if the dataframe is empty.  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the different times you apply `g` function, your dataframe changes, then it is not really a surprise that the reaction of pandas won't be  the same everytime. If you only need to apply it to the columns `B` and `C`, i suggest you type:

```
df['J'] = df[['B','C']].apply(g, axis=1)
print("J is type:  ", type(df.loc[0,'J']))
```

This way it works fine (but once again it only take the columns `B`and `C` into account).

As for the error, According to Ians it's because as soon as the output of the apply has more than 6 columns, it turns into a `DataFrame` instead of a `Series`. Then it can't be set to `df['J']`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!  I tried your first suggestion, by passing only 'B' and 'C' to the apply, like this:  `df['J'] = df[['B','C']].apply(g, axis=1)`.  And it worked!  I think it worked because of the reason @IanS gave: the number of elements in the returned series no longer matched the number of columns in the dataframe.  However, your other suggestion, in the edit, did not work for me.  Don't know why.  Also, regarding the key error, I don't think the cause was the `df.loc[0,'J']` because I think execution had already terminated before this line was run.

Comment: l@ysearka, I'll leave the question open for the moment as I'm still hoping someone can provide a general solution which works regardless of the number of columns, but thanks for the help.